# In a for loop, how can I assign the variable to a specific file-type?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, assert, os.walk

I'm using the `os.walk` command in python to go through all of a directory's contents. I'm running a secondary for loop on the files inside all of the folders and sub-folders in the directory. An error pops up saying it doesn't know how to deal with the `.txt` files present (my code is specific to `.png` files). I want the secondary for loop to run on ONLY `.png` filetypes and ignore the `.txt` or other files in the folder with the `.png` images. I tried the `assert` command, but couldn't get it to work. How can I make it restrictive to `.png` files?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"/mnt/c/Users/james/Documents/ListingTest/", topdown=True):
    for image in files:
        assert image is filetype: .png
        print(os.path.join(root, image))
```

I couldn't get the assert function syntax right and don't even know if it is the command I need to use.

Comment: `assert image.endswith('.png')`? Doesn't actually verify it's actually a PNG file (you'd need to parse every file if you wanted to be sure), but that's the simple file extension test. See chepner's comment below on how `assert` isn't what you really want anyway. You want `if not image.endswith('.png'): continue` or flip the test and put the action in the body of the `if`.

Comment: `assert` is intended to terminate your program; it doesn't simply skip this iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for image in files:
    if image.lower().endswith(".png"):
        print(os.path.join(root, image))
```

This would print all the paths of files ending with `.png`. As mentioned in the comments, this does not actually guarantee that the file is an image. Any file with the mentioned extension will be printed.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much